# How to make my jquery tilted slider automatic?

Tags: jquery

I got this from https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/TiltedContentSlideshow/

But I am unable to make this sliding automatic.. I tried some but didn't work

i dont know how to code this so i can make it slide automatic

**Code:**

```
( function( window ) {

    'use strict';

    // https://gist.github.com/edankwan/4389601
    Modernizr.addTest('csstransformspreserve3d', function () {
        var prop = Modernizr.prefixed('transformStyle');
        var val = 'preserve-3d';
        var computedStyle;
        if(!prop) return false;

        prop = prop.replace(/([A-Z])/g, function(str,m1){ return '-' + m1.toLowerCase(); }).replace(/^ms-/,'-ms-');

        Modernizr.testStyles('#modernizr{' + prop + ':' + val + ';}', function (el, rule) {
            computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle ? getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue(prop) : '';
        });

        return (computedStyle === val);
    });

    var support = { 
            animations : Modernizr.cssanimations,
            preserve3d : Modernizr.csstransformspreserve3d,
            transforms3d : Modernizr.csstransforms3d
        },
        isSupported = support.animations && support.preserve3d && support.transforms3d,
        animEndEventNames = {
            'WebkitAnimation' : 'webkitAnimationEnd',
            'OAnimation' : 'oAnimationEnd',
            'msAnimation' : 'MSAnimationEnd',
            'animation' : 'animationend'
        },
        // animation end event name
        animEndEventName = animEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'animation' ) ];

    function extend( a, b ) {
        for( var key in b ) { 
            if( b.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
                a[key] = b[key];
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    function TiltSlider( el, options ) {
        this.el = el;
        // available effects for the animations (animation class names) - when a item comes in / out
        this.animEffectsOut = ['moveUpOut','moveDownOut','slideUpOut','slideDownOut','slideLeftOut','slideRightOut'];
        this.animEffectsIn = ['moveUpIn','moveDownIn','slideUpIn','slideDownIn','slideLeftIn','slideRightIn'];
        // the items
        this.items = this.el.querySelector( 'ol.slides' ).children;
        // total items
        this.itemsCount = this.items.length;
        if( !this.itemsCount ) return;
        // index of the current item
        this.current = 0;
        this.options = extend( {}, this.options );
        extend( this.options, options );
        this._init();
    }

    TiltSlider.prototype.options = {};

    TiltSlider.prototype._init = function() {
        this._addNavigation();
        this._initEvents();
    };

    // add the navigation to the DOM
    TiltSlider.prototype._addNavigation = function() {
        // add nav "dots"
        this.nav = document.createElement( 'nav' );
        var inner = '';
        for( var i = 0; i < this.itemsCount; ++i ) {
            inner += i === 0 ? '<span class="current"></span>' : '<span></span>';
        }
        this.nav.innerHTML = inner;
        this.el.appendChild( this.nav );
        this.navDots = [].slice.call( this.nav.children );
    };

    TiltSlider.prototype._initEvents = function() {
        var self = this;
        // show a new item when clicking the navigation "dots"
        this.navDots.forEach( function( dot, idx ) {
            dot.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
                if( idx !== self.current ) {
                    self._showItem( idx );
                }
            } );
        } );
    };

    TiltSlider.prototype._showItem = function( pos ) {
        if( this.isAnimating ) {
            return false;
        }
        this.isAnimating = true;

        classie.removeClass( this.navDots[ this.current ], 'current' );

        var self = this,
            // the current item
            currentItem = this.items[ this.current ];

        this.current = pos;

        // next item to come in
        var nextItem = this.items[ this.current ],
            // set random effects for the items
            outEffect = this.animEffectsOut[ Math.floor( Math.random() * this.animEffectsOut.length ) ],
            inEffect = this.animEffectsIn[ Math.floor( Math.random() * this.animEffectsOut.length ) ];

        currentItem.setAttribute( 'data-effect-out', outEffect );
        nextItem.setAttribute( 'data-effect-in', inEffect );

        classie.addClass( this.navDots[ this.current ], 'current' );

        var cntAnims = 0,
            // the number of elements that actually animate inside the current item
            animElemsCurrentCount = currentItem.querySelector( '.tiltview' ).children.length, 
            // the number of elements that actually animate inside the next item
            animElemsNextCount = nextItem.querySelector( '.tiltview' ).children.length,
            // keep track of the number of animations that are terminated
            animEndCurrentCnt = 0, animEndNextCnt = 0,
            // check function for the end of each animation
            isFinished = function() {
                ++cntAnims;
                if( cntAnims === 2 ) {
                    self.isAnimating = false;
                }
            },
            // function for the end of the current item animation
            onEndAnimationCurrentItem = function() {
                ++animEndCurrentCnt;
                var endFn = function() {
                    classie.removeClass( currentItem, 'hide' );
                    classie.removeClass( currentItem, 'current' );
                    isFinished();
                };

                if( !isSupported ) {
                    endFn();
                }
                else if( animEndCurrentCnt === animElemsCurrentCount ) {
                    currentItem.removeEventListener( animEndEventName, onEndAnimationCurrentItem );
                    endFn();
                }
            },
            // function for the end of the next item animation
            onEndAnimationNextItem = function() {
                ++animEndNextCnt;
                var endFn = function() {
                    classie.removeClass( nextItem, 'show' );
                    classie.addClass( nextItem, 'current' );
                    isFinished();
                };

                if( !isSupported ) {
                    endFn();
                }
                else if( animEndNextCnt === animElemsNextCount ) {
                    nextItem.removeEventListener( animEndEventName, onEndAnimationNextItem );
                    endFn();
                }
            };

        classie.addClass( currentItem, 'hide' );
        classie.addClass( nextItem, 'show' );

        if( isSupported ) {
            currentItem.addEventListener( animEndEventName, onEndAnimationCurrentItem );
            nextItem.addEventListener( animEndEventName, onEndAnimationNextItem );
        }
        else {
            onEndAnimationCurrentItem();
            onEndAnimationNextItem();
        }
    };

    // add to global namespace
    window.TiltSlider = TiltSlider;

})( window );
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried yet? Please make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your existing code and add the link to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your response!. As I have mentioned above I got code from the link mentioned. I don't know how to make it slide it automatic.

Comment: I pasted my code in jsfiddle but didn't see animation effects.

Comment: but its working fine, when I run it on local host

Comment: sorted! I have used this code and triggered

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
        new TiltSlider( document.getElementById( 'slideshow' ) );               
        window.setInterval(function(){              
            $('nav>.current').next().trigger('click');
            if($('nav > .current').next().index() == '-1'){
                $('nav > span').trigger('click');
            }               
        }, 5000);

        });

Comment: Good you solved it. Could you phrase an answer from your solution and mark this as answered? This helps clean up SO from (answered) unanswered questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please put the following code in your script.

$(document).ready(function(){ new TiltSlider( document.getElementById( 'slideshow' ) ); window.setInterval(function(){ $('nav>.current').next().trigger('click'); if($('nav > .current').next().index() == '-1'){ $('nav > span').trigger('click'); } }, 5000); });

this determines the click function for the span.

speed for the slider you can set >5000<.